# how to fix SQL server Json text is not properly formatted. Unexpected character is found at position 151

Tags: sql, json-query, json-value

Im working on a table that has a column in JSON format and I want to extact the coordinate value from that column.

So I run the following code:

```
Select *,JSON_VALUE(field,'$."Coordinate-X"[0]') As coordinate INTO TABLE_1 FROM table
WHERE JSON_VALUE(field,'$."Coordinate-X"[0]') IS NOT NULL
```

And I get the following error after 5 mins of running

> Msg 13609, Level 16, State 1, Line 27
> Json text is not properly formatted. Unexpected character '"' is found at position 151.

When I try to check some rows with top 200 * below code returns results withour any error

```
Select TOP 200 *,JSON_QUERY(field,'$."Coordinate-X"[0]') As coordinate FROM table
WHERE JSON_VALUE(field,'$."Coordinate-X"[0]') IS NOT NULL
```

I guess I have a row that is causing the error but I dont know how to identify it or exclude that row and return the results.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> I managed to run around the problem with this where statement in case someone has same problem I hope it helps!

```
Select *,JSON_QUERY(field,'$."Coordinate-X"[0]') As coordinate FROM table
WHERE field like '%Coordinate-X%'
and ISJSON(field)=1
```

Answer (score 3):

seems like you have bad data( in your case doublequote)  in your JSON field.
your TOP 200 runs successfully because that bad character is not showing on TOP 200..
I suggest if you don't have a check constraint on that column add one to avoid bad

```
ALTER TABLE tablename ADD CONSTRAINT JSON_CHECK CHECK (ISJSON(field) = 1 )
```

character in your JSON data:
.,to add double quote as part of values in your JSON it shuld look like this : `"JSON Value with \" in the value"`

for example `[{"Id":3,"Title":"JSON Value with \" in the value"}]`

Comment: provide us some sample data